# Eclipse: how to install Subclipse on Eclipse (Indigo) [on Linux]

Tags: linux, eclipse, subclipse

I am trying to install Subclipse on Linux. My Eclipse (Indigo) version is 3.7.2. I went to [this site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) and copied the link says:

Links for 1.8.x Release:
Zipped downloads: http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240

but it is not working...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In eclipse, go to help --> Install New Software...
Then put this URL in the box (this URL is from the site that you link to).

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

The plugins will then appear for you to select.

Or you can click on help --> Eclipse Marketplace... 
and then search for Subclipse if you have the marketplace installed.

Comment: My Eclipse Indigo doesn't have a Marketplace item.

Comment: If you need the updated version 1.12, use this link: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.12.x